# Insufficient privilege to run as user SSRS and CRM2011

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am attempting to generate a Dynamics CRM 2011 SSRS report programatically.

I am receiving the following error:

```
Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: Caller S-1-5-21-3239909829-2541432921-3578859411-1114 has insufficient privilege to run report as user 519f1b51-1f3a-e411-80be-00155d823202
```

The second Guid is the id of the CRM user that I use to authenticate against the CRM and the credntials of who are passed to the report. (CRM Reports take the userid as a username and the organisation id as the password).

The first Guid is, I suspect, the user that my SSRS reporting service runs under (domain\sql_reports)

Firstly, this works fine in my development environment (I hate saying that).
Secondly, I have checked the following:

- sql_reports user is a member of the appropriate PrivUserGroup, PrivReportingGroup, SqlAccessGroup and ReportingGroup
- I can correctly run the report via CRM
- I can correclty run the report via the `http://server/reports` interface when I supply the appropriate credentials

The error I receive is only when I programtically attempt to generate this report from a custom application. As mentioned above, this is only an issue in the production environment. I have other components of this application that read/write to the CRM without any issue in the production environment.

I am running SQL Server 2012 & Reporting Services, and Dynamics CRM 2011 (all components are patched to UR17).

The SQL Server, Reporting Services & Dynamics Reporting Extensions are installed on one machine and CRM is installed on another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check this link :  http://crmentropy.blogspot.in/2012/12/ssrs-execution-account-needs.html#comment-form

Comment: Thanks, but that error is slightly different and I have not specified any Execution account for SSRS

Comment: ok, then make sure you are executing that report as a administrator.